# finding local maxima in 3D images

Tags: matlab, 3d, processing

I want to use a 3D blob detector which is a filtration algorithm, used for detection of spherical object in images. In this filter voxels with value greater than all pixels in their 26-neighborhood are set to 1

```
(s(x,y,z)=max(n26(x,y,z)))
```

and every other pixel is set to `0`. Is there any function in matlab to do this work?

```
M(x,y,z)={ 1 if s(x,y,z)=max(n26(x,y,z))   
           0 otherwise
```

Answer (score 4):

The easiest way to find local maxima is to use `imdilate`:

```
%# s = 3D array
msk = true(3,3,3);
msk(2,2,2) = false;
%# assign, to every voxel, the maximum of its neighbors
s_dil = imdilate(s,msk);
M = s > s_dil; %# M is 1 wherever a voxel's value is greater than its neighbors
```

Answer (score 1):

matlabs own [`imregionalmax`](http://www.mathworks.de/de/help/images/ref/imregionalmax.html?searchHighlight=imregionalmax) supports 26n from the get go, output is a logical.

2D example with 8n:

```
A =

     1     1     1     1     1     1     1     1
     1     3     3     3     1     1     4     1
     1     3     5     3     1     4     4     4
     1     3     3     3     1     4     4     4
     1     1     1     1     1     4     6     4
     1     1     1     1     1     4     4     4

>> B = imregionalmax(A);
>> B

B =

     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0
     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0
     0     0     1     0     0     0     0     0
     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0
     0     0     0     0     0     0     1     0
     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0
```